# character varying vs. text as function parameter types in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, datatypes, string

Is there any significant difference (in performance for example) between `character varying` vs. `text` as types for db function parameters? I have 2 usage examples:

Example 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1(table_name <character varying|text>)
  RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  RESULT integer;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || table_name INTO result;
  RETURN result;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func2(filter_value <character varying|text>)
  RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  RESULT integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO RESULT FROM <some_table> WHERE <some_column> = filter_value;
  RETURN result;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

NOTE in the 2nd example the `some_column` type is `text` if `filter_value` is of type `character varying` and vice versa

Comment: No difference at all. Neither in performance nor in memory. In general using `text` is easier as all unknown string literals are assumed to be `text`

Comment: Example1 - I think it doesn't matter what datatype is used. Example2 - the same datatype which `<some_column>` have is recommended (but in general it doesn't matter too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to performance, these data types are exactly the same, down to the implementation in C.

If in doubt, use `text`, because that is the *preferred type* of its *type class*, and the [data type resolution rules for functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-func.html) will resolve all unknown strings to `text` implicitly. With `character varying` you often have to use explicit type casts.